# How to extract file name with extension from parent path? MS Access VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I want to get the name of the file with its extension after the parent file path. For example: retrieve picture.jpg from C:\Desktop\Pictures\picture.jpg. *Note: I do not know what the name of the file or picture is going to be. Users will add those themselves and I want to retrieve the name to display it on a form.

Here is what I have so far...

```
Private Sub InsertImageButton_Click()
Dim strImageID As String
Dim strFolder As String
Dim fso As Object
Dim strFormat As String

Const strParent = "C:\Desktop\Pictures\"

strImageID = Me.ImageID.Value
strFormat = Format(strImageID, "20-0000")

'Parent Path
strFolder = strParent & strFormat

'Create FileSystemObject
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
'Check Whether Folder Exists
If fso.FolderExists(strFolder) = False Then
'If not, create it
    fso.CreateFolder strFolder
End If

'Open It
Shell "C:\Windows\explorer.exe """ & strFolder & "", vbNormalFocus
```

*When the folder opens, this is where the user should insert a new picture.
After this I want the textbox to display the full path name so it can get the name of the picture as well.

```
'This is where I am stuck.
Me.[txtImageName].Value = strFolder & "\" & GetFilenameFromPath(strFolder)
```

I tried adding a function from other Stack Overflow questions but it didn't help.

```
Public Function GetFilenameFromPath(ByVal strPath As String) As String
' Returns the rightmost characters of a string upto but not including the rightmost '\'
' e.g. 'c:\winnt\win.ini' returns 'win.ini'
Dim picturepath As String
    If Right$(strPath, 1) <> "\" And Len(strPath) > 0 Then
        GetFilenameFromPath = GetFilenameFromPath(Left$(strPath, Len(strPath) - 1)) + Right$(strPath, 1)
    End If
End Function
```

The current code gives me C:\Desktop\Pictures\20-0012\20-0012
I need the name of the picture added without knowing what was added.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I tested GetFilenameFromPath function and it returns "picture.jpg" from "C:\Desktop\Pictures\picture.jpg". Code is unnecessarily complex but it works. So whatever issue is, it's not with that function.

Comment: Me.[txtImageName].Value = strFolder & "\" & GetFilenameFromPath(strFolder). So is this correct? I am not sure how to use the function and txtImageName.Value at the same time?

Comment: The function returns correct output when it receives a full filepath string. Probably need to modify FSO dialog code to select file, not folder. Why are you opening Windows Explorer?

Comment: The problem is that I don't know the full filepath string. I only know the parent filepath. I need to get picture.jpg by only being able to see C:\Desktop\Pictures\ (picture.jpg is the unknown and I need a way to find it).

Comment: Can't find what is unknown. If a full filepath is already saved in record then why do you need to extract filename part?

Comment: What did you want accomplishing, in fact? I answered your clear question (retrieve picture.jpg from C:\Desktop\Pictures\picture.jpg.). What string does `Me.ImageID.Value` contain? Should it be only an extension? And you need to retrieve all files in the folder path having that specific extension?

Comment: Me.ImageID.Value is the record number. Upon new record the code adds a file with that record number such as C:\Desktop\Pictures\20-0023. The code I have above InsertImageButton_Click() opens up that 20-0023 folder (it's empty). The user should add a picture and I want my textbox to display the filepath of the picture added...Should look like C:\Desktop\Pictures\20-0023\unknown.jpg

Comment: Loop through folder contents until encounters file with acceptable name.

Comment: If it is a single file inside, no need to loop. Try my suggestion in the adapted code, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the next function, please:

```
Function GetFileName(strFullName As String) As String
    GetFileName = Split(strFullName, "\")(UBound(Split(strFullName, "\")))
End Function
```

The above function should be tested in this way, if the folder in discussion contains a single file:

```
dim fullFileName As String
fullFileName = Dir(strFolder & "\*.jpg")
MsgBox GetFileName(fullFileName)
```

Comment: Should I replace strFullName with my strFolder?

Comment: @SharonIsKaren: Yes. I edited the answer in order to show how to be tested/called.

Comment: MsgBox still give me 20-0020. strFolder is only C:\Desktop\Pictures\20-0020      I need the file inside it, which should be another file that's unknown.

Comment: I asked you in a comment: What `Me.ImageID.Value` returns? Isn't it the file name?

Comment: Is it a jpg file?

Comment: @SharonIsKaren: for a single jpg file, please test the updated solution, showing how to use the function.

Comment: This works with Dir(strFolder & "\*.jpg"). Thank you! Now what if it can be whatever? Such as .pdf, or .png. Should I just remove the .jpg and look for only that one file?

Comment: @SharonIsKaren:  Yes. And if there are more such files in the folder, it is possible to iterate between each other and return all of them name. If needed, I can show how to proceed...

Comment: @SharonIsKaren: But, did my solution answer your question? If yes, we here tick the code left side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. If not, please clarify what part of the question was not answered?

Comment: Can wildcard extension as well: `strFolder & "*.*"`

Comment: @June7: Yes. But the idea was to retrieve a specific extension type file (jpg). But, yes, if no other file would exist, and file type does not matter, it works...

Comment: But they did ask "if it can be whatever?" in comment - just responding to that.

Comment: @June7: Reading again what he said, it looks you understood him it better then me... :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Function GetFilenameFromPath(ByVal strPath As String) As String
    GetFilenameFromPath = Mid(strPath, InStrRev(strPath, "\") + 1)
End Function
```